# Символ * в регулярных выражениях js

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php, javascript

Здравствуйте. Почему регулярка

```
var rep = /[^\*a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9_-]/g;
```

Работает как надо, а регулярка

```
var rep = /[^a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9_-\*]/g;
```

Даёт ошибку range out of order in character class? То же самое и в php.

Comment: потому что тире обозначает диапазон символьного класса, и символьного класса `_-*` не существует.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что "-" указывает на то, что используется диапазон символов.
Соответственно, такая конструкция

```
_-\*
```

интерпретируются так: **выбрать символы с "_" по "*"**

Определения такого диапазона, естественно, нет, поэтому выдается ошибка.

Символ "-" указывают в конце перечисления, чтобы не приходилось его экранировать.
Для вашего случая правильная запись будет такой:

```
var rep = /[^a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9_\-\*]/g;
```

Comment: то есть, сам того не зная, сделал правильно. До тех пор, пока не захотел добавить звёздочку.
Спасибо.